# How to display text in center of an indeterminate ProgressBar (spinning wheel)?

Tags: android

How to display text in center of an indeterminate ProgressBar (spinning wheel)?

I want to display seconds in the center. Using android API-19.
The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) say that to show progress, horizontal bar must be used. 
However, if I can display text in the center, then that will work for me.

So again, how do I set the text to display in a spinning wheel progress bar?

(I would prefer to try to use the existing API before running off to build a custom Progress Bar)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mycom.countdowntimer.CountdownMainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add a textview in the XML

Comment: @pedro where? see xml above

Comment: What type of layout is the progressbar parent?

Comment: @pedro I am flexible with layout - can change it to whatever will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this text to your layout

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5 s"
    android:id="@+id/txt_secondsleft"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/progressBar1"
   />
```

You can use it to display the text you want and it will be centered on your progressbar

Comment: great! I didn't realize the textview could display in the center of the wheel by setting the layout alignment values.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried and found the solution. Use the xml, It will align the text in the center of wheel. Hope this will help you.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/prograss_bar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="loading" />
</RelativeLayout>
```